# XPath expression for last <a> element whose "href" attribute starts with a number?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I would like to find an XPath expression which, when applied to the page at:

> https://ftp.opera.com/pub/opera-beta/

will return the text of the final `<a>` element whose `href` attribute value starts with a number.

If I had just wanted the final `<a>` element I could have simply written:

> //body/pre/a[last()]/text()

but unfortunately the last element on this page looks like this:

```
<a href="info/">info/</a>
```

What I want is the last element **whose `href` attribute has a value that starts with a number**.  This is currently this value:

```
<a href="41.0.2353.30/">41.0.2353.30/</a>
```

so what alternate XPath expression can I use to return the last value that starts with a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `(//a[number(substring(@href, 1, 1)) = number(substring(@href, 1, 1))])[last()]` you select the last `a` element in the document with a `href` attribute where the first character is a number.

Comment: Fantastic!  "(//body/pre/a[number(substring(@href, 1, 1)) = number(substring(@href, 1, 1))])[last()]/text()" finds the exact text I am looking for.  Many thanks.

Comment: @gepree, then this answer can be accepted as answer instead of just thanks.